# Evaluation of not and addition operations on boolean values

Tags: python, boolean

Can someone please explain the order of operations in these two code snippets? I don't understand why I get different outputs: `True` in the case of:

```py
print(not not True + True + False)
```

and `2` in the case of:

```py
print((not not True) + True + False)
```

Comment: `not not True` equals `True` ; and `True`+`True`+`False` = 2. When adding boolean values python treas True as 1 and False as 0

Comment: Thanks for reiterating, needed confirmation on this. So you have answered the second part; let me know if you can comment on the first one as well.

Comment: all integer values are interpreted as True except 0 is interpreted as False. Also `not` before addition

Comment: Someone freshly answered, but just to address, you were still answering the second part of the question. The first part goes: ```print(not not True + True + False)``` and produces the output ```True```. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Using [this table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) for operator precedence, we see that `+` has a higher precedence than `not`. So:

```py
not not True + True + False
```

is equivalent to

```py
not not (True + True + False)
```

which is equivalent to

```py
not not (2)
```

which is equivalent to

```py
not False
```

which is equivalent to

```py
True
```

---

We can follow a similar procedure for the second print:

```py
(not not True) + True + False
```

is equivalent to:

```py
True + True + False
```

which, by boolean addition, results in:

```py
2
```